# Get 2nd dose of COVID vaccine in the US as a tourist

Tags: usa, covid-19, canadian-citizens, medical-tourism

I recently got my 1st dose of (Pfizer) COVID vaccine in Canada and might have to wait 2-4 months (likely 2) for my 2nd dose.

I don't want to get into the debate about whether this is acceptable from a medical point of view. Let's just say - I want to do whatever I can to follow the manufacturer's guidelines and get the 2nd dose within a 3-6 week window.

To this end, I plan to travel to Dallas to get my 2nd dose.

My main question is this: What do I tell the border agent? Just that I am there to get a 2nd shot? I think this may not be good because an agent may not like it even if there is no law that says I can't visit for this purpose (lot of Canadians travel for cancer treatment for example).

Should I just not mention vaccines and say that I am there to visit friends? I do actually have friends in Dallas that I would like to see in a socially distanced/outdoor setting.

I chose Dallas, because this is the only direct flight from Toronto to a US state where it is explicitly stated that vaccines have no residency or citizenship requirements. So this seems the least risky option in terms of time spent in planes and airports.

I plan to stay in an airport hotel, take the vaccine and PCR test (for return to Canada) at the nearest pharmacy on the same day, have 1 day to recover and fly back to Canada on day 3.

Of course, I plan to double mask anytime I am indoors and follow all the protocols. Having a few weeks' time after the 1st shot should give me some protection too.

From what I can see, the uptake of vaccines has reduced drastically in Texas. On Dallas forums, I read about mass vaccination sites closing down and there are endless open appointments on pharmacy websites. So I feel that I am not really depriving an American of a vaccine. Also, spending thousands of dollars on an American hotel, American airline, rental car company, PCR test lab etc. should make up for me taking a free dose.

Update: Of course, I will quarantine when I get back to Canada as well and hopefully reduce the wait for a 2nd dose for someone else.

Comment: https://www.reuters.com/business/healthcare-pharmaceuticals/vaccine-tourism-canadians-fly-south-shot-us-demand-falls-2021-05-05/ sounds like plenty of people are doing this without any attempt to hide it

Comment: @ajd Yes, they are not hiding it from the media. But I wonder if this is what they said to the border agent? One of them seemed to have a side reason of meeting clients.

Comment: Don't forget there is currently [mandatory designated hotel quarantine](https://www.canada.ca/en/public-health/services/diseases/2019-novel-coronavirus-infection/latest-travel-health-advice/mandatory-hotel-stay-air-travellers.html) at your own expense for minimum 3 days if you fly back. More if your test does not come back negative.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am ok with that. Not OK with possible long term effects of incorrect dosage spacing.

Comment: Couldn't you get it anywhere closer?  It'd be a lot safer to drive a car to North Dakota (for example) rather than get in a plane.  I heard North Dakota has been vaccinating Canadian truckers.

Comment: @gerrit I live in Ontario, how would I get to Manitoba? I would need to drive for 22 hours and take hotel stops along the way. Also, I am not a trucker or essential worker, so I cannot cross to US border by land.

Comment: For what it's worth, Ohio doesn't have residency requirements and there's abundant vaccine availability. Nor, as I understand it, do Michigan or Pennsylvania. Much closer to Ontario by car.

Comment: @SamHanley thank you. I am aware of that. But land border is closed except to essential workers, the only way I can enter US soil is by flying. And no direct flights to those states.

Comment: @HalfVaxxedCanadian North Dakota was just an example.  How can you get to Texas if you can't cross the US border?  Do they allow more people to enter by air than by land?  If you can fly to Texas for medical reasons, can't you drive to Michigan for medical reasons?

Comment: @HalfVaxxedCanadian I didn't realize the rules were different for flying versus driving, thanks for clarifying. That's very interesting. Best of luck!

Comment: Yes, rules are totally different for flying vs driving. The bar for driving is much much higher. Whereas anyone can fly in for whatever reason currently.

Comment: Here in Colorado, when you go for a second dose, you're expected to present your CDC vaccine card showing the date and type of the first dose.  I don't know if they'd accept your Canadian card.

Comment: Good point @NateEldredge, I have read conflicting accounts and doesnt seem to be a universal practice, I will call them and ask

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While this [page](https://ca.usembassy.gov/travel-restrictions-fact-sheet/) "does not apply to entry into the United States from Canada via air" it still offers some valuable insight.

Visiting friends would be:

> The following categories do not fall within the definition of “essential travel:”
> Individuals traveling for tourism purposes, such as sightseeing, recreation, gambling, or attending cultural events in the United States.

However:

> Who is considered an “essential” traveler

> Individuals traveling for medical purposes (e.g., to receive medical treatment in the United States).

Therefore the simplest is to tell the truth: state you are seeking medical treatment not available in Canada. This would be accepted even on a land border. On further enquire, if there is one, I do not see why stating you are there for the vaccine would be a problem. This is always the best tactic with border control: never lie and never offer information unasked for.

This https://www.ctvnews.ca/health/coronavirus/vaccine-tourism-canadians-fly-south-for-shot-as-u-s-demand-falls-1.5416756 article offers stories where people openly went for the vaccine.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. The reason I thought stating vaccines as the primary reason would be an issue is that it could be perceived as taking advantage of the US and border agents are known to react emotionally.

Comment: It IS taking advantage, since the US taxpayers have paid for them.

Comment: @WGroleau how much does 1 dose cost? I know Israel paid $30 per dose. I will donate that to the US treasury, if that makes you happy. I will probably pay more than that in sales taxes while I am in Dallas.

Comment: I have no idea what they cost.  Knowing the way our Pharma works, probably ten times what they should have cost.  Don't take it personally.  You said "perceived" and I was just clarifying.  Am I taking advantage when I buy my meds OTC in Spain for less than half of my US co-pay?

Comment: @HalfVaxxedCanadian Please note that 'cost of vaccine' is just a fraction of the total cost. Compare for example how a self-paid PCR test costs around $20 in Nepal, $80 in the EU and around $100-$200 in the US.

Comment: @WGroleau On the other hand, if US were willing to export vaccines to Canada, OP would probably have had their second dose by now.

Comment: @DavidMulder From the news reports I have read, Israel pays the highest per dose. Lets assume US matched it. That is $30 per dose. Yes, the US govt gives it to people for 'free', so thats where your 'fraction' cost theory comes in. Money spent to subsidize Pfizer? Well, BionTech and Pfizer rejected US govt subsidy (Moderna took it). So again, I am not taking money from US taxpayer. 
I know that WGroleau clarified its just perception and not his belief, but the upvotes to his earlier comment shows the ignorance of some people, the exact kind of ignorance I fully expect from a border agent.

Comment: If the poster's stated purpose for entry is for "medial purposes" is there a chance the border agent would ask for proof? (A scheduled appointment, etc.?)

Comment: @HalfVaxxedCanadian Money spend on people giving the shot, opportunity cost of having the same health personnel not doing something else, etc. My point with the PCR tests is that the cost of the test itself is less than those $20, but by the time you pay for the entire system to allow you to actually take the test in the US it works out to between $100 to $200. What the total cost is in the US for the vaccine shots I have no idea about, I just wanted to point out that the cost of the substance is just a small fraction.

Comment: @DavidMulder Got it, so add the 30 minutes of time the CVS worker will spend on me (they aint spending it on others because appointments are lying empty). How much do the CVS employees make per hour? $50? Lets say thay make $100 per hour (200k per year) to incl opp cost. 30 minutes on me $50. I will add that to the dose cost of $30 (80 total) and donate it to the US treasury to keep everyone happy. Note, even if I didnt, sales taxes on my AA ticket is more than that. I am going to a private lab for PCR testing and it costs $275, I highly doubt that is subsidized by taxpayers.

Comment: If we keep at this long enough, I am sure we will come to the conclusion that the thousands of dollars I am spending on private goods and services along with the sales taxes on those are more than enough to cover whatever costs I will incur. But there is no time for this at the border and a simpleton agent will reach the low effort conclusion of "tHeY tOoK uRr jAbS!"

Comment: The US could fix it tomorrow by charging $1000 for vaccines to non residents if they really feel like they are being taken advantage of and I and others would gladly pay up.

Comment: @HalfVaxxedCanadian, I doubt anyone you bump into will take the opinion that you are "stealing a jab" from an American. Any American who still wants one is without an excuse. The rush of demand is over here; no one is lining up and from your own observation, most of the clinics are doing walk-ins now. The US is currently discussing selling some does to other countries. If anything there is a glut of supply based on the demand, and IMHO any dose going to someone who wants/needs it (rather than being wasted) is a plus from a humanitarian perspective.

Comment: @HalfVaxxedCanadian if Texas has "explicitly stated that vaccines have no residency or citizenship requirements" then it doesn't matter whether you're taking advantage; the US and Texas political processes have explicitly concluded that it's acceptable regardless of whether anyone considers that it is taking advantage. Granted, an immigration officer might not see it that way. Also, because of the lowered demand, recent headlines indicate that states are passing up allocated doses. It may be that Canada will get some of those doses, reducing your wait for a second dose in Canada.

Comment: @spuck at the land border _yes_ via air, likely not.

Comment: @WGroleau The economic benefit of each vaccine shot are [estimated at $5800](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/371/6534/1107). So if the vaccine shot cost $50 to the US government, its still a 1:100 return on investment. Assuming only 10% of the economic output of a Canadian will benefit the US, that's still a 1:10 ROI. The economics of vaccine production are very counter-intuitive. For the same reason paying for vaccinations against tropical diseases in other countries has a great ROI for the US economy as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is all probably moot for Canadians now, but in case anyone is interested, I can share my experience.

I found a legitimate reason for me to be in the States (I don't want to share it) and the CBP officer had no issues with that. I took the vaccine in a Dallas CVS.

I got a CDC card with just the 2nd dose written on it and also an online receipt from CVS with the lot number and my details. Upon my return to Canada (post July 5), the physical card was accepted as proof of my vaccination (along with my 1st dose receipt that I received in Canada). I was able to avoid quarantine.

What is more interesting is that I overheard other officers actively encouraging other Canadians to get their 2nd shot in the US, even though the travelers didn't ask.

I hope people from other countries go and take their vaccines, wherever they can get it.

Comment: It should be noted, that the rules and regulations of the country you are traveling to is what counts. For travel to areas where these local forms are compleatly unknown is not a good idea. Getting an **International Certificate of Vaccination** booklet it the better option. Your doctor can fill out the needed entry and stamp it.