# Am I considered fully vaccinated for travel purposes if I have 6 weeks between the 1 and 2 doses?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, indonesia

I got Pfizer COVID-19 vaccine. The time interval between the first and second doses was 40 days. I know ideally they want 21 days. However, I couldn’t make it, so here I am.

Is this going to be sufficient for international travel? I need to fly from the USA to Indonesia. Am I considered full vaccinated? Or does it have to be *exactly* 21 days?

Comment: Whether your vaccination circumstances meets the requirements of your destination depends on the destination. "South East Asia" isn't enough specificity. Into what country will you arrive?

Comment: 21 might have been the initial advise from Pfizer, but they have softened that quite a bit. Some of the people who got the vaccinate first here in Denmark probably got their two shots with an interval of 21 days, but later in the process that became quite abnormal - I think the interval between my two shots was 36 days.

Comment: Actually 3 vs 4 weeks is thought to one of the reasons why the Pfizer vac is doing slightly worse than Moderna.

Comment: Note that as of today you’ll still need to quarantine in Jakarta for 5 days even when vaccinated, when coming from the US (or most other countries)

Comment: In the UK the standard time between doses was extended to 12 weeks so that the number of people covered by at least one dose could be maximised.

Comment: @uɐɪ and then reduced to 8 once we had high coverage and excess capacity.

Comment: @Tim 8 weeks is still longer than the 6 weeks that the OP was worried about.

Comment: @uɐɪ, Tim Which in itsself is a sign that **being exactly an X amount days** is not really a major problem.

Comment: There was this story, that it took 16 weeks to get the second shot in Canada: [Get 2nd dose of COVID vaccine in the US as a tourist](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163670/get-2nd-dose-of-covid-vaccine-in-the-us-as-a-tourist). Most people did not get their second shot exactly 21 days after the first. Where did you get the idea it has to be exactly 21 days?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The official recommendation from Pfizer is that the 2nd dose should be received between 3 and 6 weeks from the date of the 1st dose. This recommendation is mirrored by the [US CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/second-shot.html), as well as the [World Health Organization](https://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/handle/10665/341786/WHO-2019-nCoV-vaccines-SAGE-recommendation-BNT162b2-2021.2-eng.pdf) (WHO).

As you received your 2nd dose 40 days after the first, you are (just!) within the 3-6 week window, and thus would be considered fully vaccinated.

Indonesia specifically does not appear to have stated any requirements around vaccine timing, and in general most countries are taking the approach that if you are vaccinated within the rules of your home country, then you are considered vaccinated (although this does NOT always apply to the type of vaccine used, just the timing).

Answer (score 9):

You need not worry about a slight delay after (what in many countries is considered) the **minimal/maximum period** of 3/6 weeks for the **Comirnaty/BioNTech/Pfizer** vaccinations.

The goal of the minimal period is to **swiftly offer protection** against the delta variant.

The **maximum period** (6 weeks) is considered to offer the **optimal protection** for this specific vaccination product.

Since these values are based on practical experience collected and shared around the world, it is unlikely that individual countries will have radically different recommendations.

One should, however, always check the recommendations of the country one is travelling to, as well as being aware of **the different names used** for the same vaccination product.

**Comirnaty** is the name of the vaccine, developed by **BioNTech** and produced by **Pfizer** (as one of many products).

---

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

[RKI - Impfen - COVID-19 und Impfen: Antworten auf häufig gestellte Fragen (FAQ)](https://www.rki.de/SharedDocs/FAQ/COVID-Impfen/gesamt.html)

For **Comirnaty/BioNTech/Pfizer** the recommendation is 3 to 6 weeks.

> At the beginning of April 2021, a vaccination interval of 6 weeks was initially recommended for the mRNA vaccines, as this should achieve the best balance between good individual protection and optimal civil protection.  Findings on vaccination with regard to the delta variant show a significantly better protective effect after the second vaccine dose, especially against severe courses.  A shorter vaccination interval therefore leads to better protection both for the individual and for the population in a timely manner.

For **Spikevax/Moderna** the recommendation is 4 to 6 weeks.

For **Vaxzevria/AstraZeneca** the recommendation is 9 to 12 weeks.

> The studies showed that the interval between the two vaccine doses influences the effectiveness of the vaccination and a longer time interval has a positive effect on the level of vaccination protection.  The effectiveness of a double vaccination with an interval of 4-8 weeks was about 50%, while the effectiveness with an interval of 8-12 weeks was about 72% and with a vaccination interval of> 12 weeks it was about 75%.  These results are supported by immunogenicity data, which show that when the standard dose is administered, increasing the dose interval leads to higher antibody levels and higher GMT values ​​(<6 weeks: 22,222 (95% CI 20,360-24,225) vs. 9-11 weeks  : 34,754 (95% CI 30,287-39,879).